# Name of patterns cast as expressions from strings

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, symbols, variable, head

I'm trying to match a part of a string while imposing conditions on the patterns, e.g.:

```
StringCases["223", a: DigitCharacter ~~ b: DigitCharacter /; Unequal[a, b]]
```

what is very simple and works as expected:

```
(* {23} *)
```

However when I try to specify the names of the patterns I've put before the condition with names I've retrieved from a string, say "ab":

```
Characters["ab"]

(* {a, b} *)
```

it does not work and the condition is not successfully enforced:

```
StringCases["223", a: DigitCharacter ~~ b: DigitCharacter /;Unequal[ToExpression /@ Characters["ab"]]]

(* {22} *)
```

Why doesn't it work, in spite of taking the precaution of converting the string characters returned from `Characters` to symbols? Aren't those strings, cast as symbols, proper variables (I'm suspicious since their color doesn't turn blue as usual and remains black, but do seem to work as regular variables)? How could I make it work this way?

Comment: try `Unequal[{1, 1}]` vs `Unequal[1,1]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
StringCases["223", a : DigitCharacter ~~ b : DigitCharacter /; 
  Evaluate[Unequal @@ (ToExpression /@ Characters["ab"])]]
```

> ```
>  {23}
> ```

Compare the evaluation of the three forms using `Trace`:

```
Trace[StringCases["223",  a : DigitCharacter ~~ b : DigitCharacter /; 
    Unequal[ToExpression /@ Characters["ab"]]] ] // Column
```

[image]

```
Trace[StringCases["223", a : DigitCharacter ~~ b : DigitCharacter /; 
   (Unequal @@ (ToExpression /@ Characters["ab"]))]] // Column
```

[image]

```
Trace[StringCases["223", a : DigitCharacter ~~ b : DigitCharacter /; 
    Evaluate[Unequal @@ (ToExpression /@ Characters["ab"])]]] // Column
```

[image]